# Leetcode producing inconsistent runtime

Tags: python, runtime

I had been trying the Greatest Sum Divisible problem on Leetcode, and when I finally managed to solve it, I ran the solution a couple of times and realized

[Inconsistent Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgwuC.png)

Leetcode had been producing really inconsistent results when it came to the runtime.

Is there any reason this may be happening from the client side or is it a server issue?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it.  May be as simple as the number of other people running the Leetcode at the same time.  Looks like noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to know the exact run time then submit it 3-4 time and take the average.

Its some bug from there back end server.